# Javascript/Jquery onclick definition of word appears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for tips on how to be able to click on a word in an html document and then for the page to update and show a definition of the word that has been clicked. It can appear at the bottom of the page. So far I'm just adding an onclick into the p tag so for instance. Am I going about this in the right way? I'm quite bad at javascript so any help with this would be great. Many thanks

```
      <p id="complexword1" onclick="functionToDisplayComplexWord()">
```

Comment: you can create library for that. Or you can just use `jquery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might help you to resolve your issue.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<p id="paragraph">Javascript/Jquery onclick definition of word appears?</p>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**(Jquery lib)

```
var p = $('p#paragraph');

p.html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>')
});

p.click(function(event) { 
    if(this.id != event.target.id) {
        alert(event.target.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fNMpw/.)

Answer (score 1):

One Solution for this might be event delegation using javascript

Assign a click event handler to the paragraph element and get the target of the event using event.target

Dummy span for each word is needed because event.target won't return text nodes in major browsers. So, you need to have dummy spans in place.

HTML

```
<p id='test'> <span>test</span> <span>test</span> <span>test</span> <span>test</span> <span>test</span> </p>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (event) { console.log(event.target.innerHTML); }, false )
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uPPMW/1/) is a demo. Check your console for output

consider using `attachEvent` and `event.srcElement` to support IE

Another solution might based on text selection.

You can get the selected text in browser using [this](http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp) code

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show in the same page or as popup?
If you are looking to use popup, [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) is a good plugin for jQuery.

If you want to do it by yourself, simply make a hidden div inside your page which you set to show in the `functionToDisplayComplexWord()`

Comment: how i do select that word using javascript. Do I need to select it via the ID that was just clicked?